# Why Is My NXT-Python Code not working over bluetooth

Tags: python, bluetooth, nxt-python

I am on my Raspberry pi  Running Python 3.9.2 And i Believe my NXT-Python version is python-3.2.0

I'm Trying to run code over Bluetooth

By the way Im Completely new to nxt-python

this is my simple program found in the nxt-python documentation

```
import nxt.locator
from nxt.motor import *

#00:16:53:15:DC:F2 is my NXTs bluetooth MAC adress

with nxt.locator.find(host="00:16:53:15:DC:F2") as b:
    print(b.get_device_info()[0:2])
```

I ran the program and got a result of

```
failed to connect to device Bluetooth (00:16:53:15:DC:F2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Mindstorms/Log.py", line 6, in <module>
    with nxt.locator.find(host="00:16:53:15:DC:F2") as b:
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/nxt/locator.py", line 215, in find
    raise BrickNotFoundError("no brick found")
nxt.locator.BrickNotFoundError: no brick found
```

And i Do have python3-bluez

Am i doing something wrong?

- Tried Uninstalling and reinstalling Nxt-Python Module.
- Tried Uninstalling and reinstalling python3-bluez.
- Tried Using USB (Worked but not wireless)

Comment: Have you tried running https://github.com/schodet/nxt-python/blob/master/scripts/nxt_test with debug turned on?  Does that give you any useful information?

Comment: That doesn't really give much information but i can try the debug code in the Documentation

Comment: Making progress When it tries to connect it says Device is busy even though my NXT is on the main menu

Comment: Been doing some research and a Module called BluSock might fix it

Comment: Nope its like bluesock got discontinued